# Why does Selberg trace formula generalize Frobenius formula for finite groups?

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Quoting Wikipedia:

> The simplest case is when $Γ$ is cocompact, when the representation breaks up into discrete summands. Here the trace formula is an extension of the Frobenius formula for the character of an induced representation of finite groups.

How do I understand this sentence? For me it seems that they are not really related. Does it mean that we can deduce Frobenius formula from the Selberg trace formula? If so, how?

Comment: The Selberg trace formula is making $PSL(2,\Bbb{R})$ act on $C^\infty(\Gamma \setminus \Bbb{H})$, the Frobenius formula is making $G$ act on $\Bbb{C}[G/H]$

Comment: @reuns The general form of Selberg trace formula makes $G$ act on $L^2(G/H)$. But why is the Frobnius formula making $G$ act on $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$? $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ is just one instance of induced representation, does this contain the general case? Could you please elaborate on that?